# Creating an ORD_MAP with Tupples as Key in SML

Tags: algorithm, structure, sml, smlnj

I'm doing an exercise in SML in which I'm in a grid and start from cell `(i,j)` and I want to go to cell `(x,y)`. To simulate this every cell is treated as a State `(i,j,move)` where move how it got there from the previous cell. Then I wrote a simple traversal algorithm (more like dfs) which starts searching the States until it finds the desired one.

Note that for the traversal function I use a Map-Dictionary which takes a State as an Index in order to keep track of the visited States.

Code:

```
val startp = (0,0)
val endp = (3,0)
val (N,M) = (4,4)

(*Define the Basic structures tht will be used*)
datatype movement = RIGHT | DOWN | LEFT | UP

type State = int * int * movement 

val firstState = (#1 startp,#2 startp,UP): State

structure STATES_KEY: ORD_KEY = 
  struct
    type ord_key = State
    val compare = fn (s1:State, s2:State) =>
      if (#1 s1 = #1 s2) andalso (#2 s1 = #2 s2)
      then EQUAL
      else if (#1 s1 > #1 s2) then GREATER
      else LESS
  end

structure StatesMap = SplayMapFn(STATES_KEY)

fun convert_ij id = (id div M, id mod N)

fun getNextStates ((i,j,_):State): State list = 
  [ (i,j+1,RIGHT),
    (i+1,j,DOWN),
    (i,j-1,LEFT),
    (i-1,j,UP)]

fun getPrevState ((i,j,move):State): State = 
  case move of 
       RIGHT => (i,j-1,UP)
     | LEFT => (i,j+1,UP)
     | UP => (i+1,j,UP)
     | DOWN => (i-1,j,UP)

(*True -> Invalid State*)
fun checkInvalidState ((i,j,_):State) = 
  if (i < 0 orelse i > N-1 orelse j < 0 orelse j > M-1)
  then true
  else false

fun checkEnd ((i,j,_):State) = 
  if (i = #1 endp andalso j = #2 endp)
  then true
  else false

fun traversal [] visited = visited
  | traversal (h::t) visited = 
  if (checkEnd h) then visited
  else if (checkInvalidState h) then traversal t visited
  else if (StatesMap.find (visited, h) = NONE)
  then 
    let
      val [s1,s2,s3,s4] = getNextStates h
    in
      traversal (s1::s2::s3::s4::t) (StatesMap.insert (visited, h, h))
    end
  else traversal t visited

val it = traversal [firstState] StatesMap.empty
```

When I run the program, it gets in an infinite loop when executing the traverse function. It goes from State: `(1,0)->(0,0)->(0,1)->(0,2)->(0,3)->(1,3)->(2,3)->(3,3)`

And from there on it keeps on going between States `(3,3)` and `(3,2)`. Also, I checked the Map struct when the traversal function is in State `(3,2)` and State `(3,3)` exists in it, meaning that it shouldn't look at it again and continue checking the other States.

What exactly doesn't work the way I think it works and causes this loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your comparison function is broken. *Edit:* For example it defines

```
(0, 2) < (0, 1)
(0, 1) < (0, 2)
```

which violates anti-symmetry. But that's a necessary property of an ordering.

You want a proper lexicographic ordering:

```
fun compare ((x1,y1,_), (x2,y2,_)) =
    case Int.compare (x1, x2) of
      EQUAL => Int.compare (y1, y2)
    | order => order
```